# Vite Expected ">" but found "class"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vite

I am getting these errors on `vite build`. It's almost like Vite has trouble parsing HTML.

```
Expected ">" but found "class"
1  | <template>
2  |      <div class="dashboard container">
   |           ^
3  |          <div class="columns has-margin-b25 has-margin-t40 is-gapless">
4  |              <div class="column is-flex">
...
n  | </template>
```

```
Unexpected "/"
1  |  <template>
2  |      <div>
3  |          <navbar></navbar>
   |                   ^
4  |          <page-header
...
n  | </template>
```

I am using Vue2, Typescript, vue-property-decorator, vue-template-compiler and vue-class-component.

A couple of interesting quirks also happen:

1. Build runs on server, but not locally. npm, node and package versions (even global packages) are all the same
2. Even locally, the build sometimes runs (every 20th run or so)
3. When it fails, it usually always fails at a different file
4. Vite dev works every time

Comment: I noticed that the last template tag is without the '>' . could you confirm me?

Comment: @Mithsew that was just a copy mistake, edited it

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you provide a reproducible code. It will help debug and answer few questions I have. Like what versions are you using for each library, and why are using vue2 with vite .. etc.

Comment: It's specific to your setup. Vite isn't responsible for this directly. It's Vue SFC loader and anything else that could be in sight. That it's a floating error makes it much more difficult to investigate,  it's unlikely that it can be solved without closely looking at it.

Comment: I've got the same error sometimes. Locally it works always, dev & build. But the buildserver is a hit & miss situation.

Comment: How did you install node? Using the UseNode@1 task made if fail for us. Maybe your node installation has something non-standard which makes it fail

Answer (score -2):

Most of the times, this kind of error is caused by html template. You can use below website to validate your html template format is correct or not.

https://validator.w3.org/